# Spring Gateway API encounters status 403 (forbidden), but in Postman I get status 200

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors, gateway

**Problem Overview:**
I have a web application built with a Java Spring Boot backend and a custom frontend using JavaScript. The frontend communicates with the backend through a Spring Cloud Gateway. The application involves user registration and login functionality.

When I try to GET or to POST user from my frontend I get status 403 (forbidden), but in contrast in Postman I get status 200 OK. I have tried now for a week to solve the issue without any luck.

Also, when I remove the Gateway API and send information directly to the microservice from the frontend I do not encounter any error. That is why I believe the issue lays somewhere in the Gateway API, hope this helps to pin point the problem that I did not find!

**Error/ Status message from my frontend**

```
UserLogin.js:9     
GET http://localhost:5000/usersRegistration/get/test@mail.com/Test$12345 403 (Forbidden)
(anonymous) @ UserLogin.js:9
UserLogin.js:14 

UserLogin.js:26 Error: Error: Login failed. Invalid credentials.
    at UserLogin.js:18:23
```

**Postman view**
[image: Postman status view 200 OK]

**Gateway API**

```
package webapplication.gatewayapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:63343")
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("usersRegistration", r -> r.path("/usersRegistration/**")
                        .uri("http://localhost:5001"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Gateway application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 5000

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOriginPatterns: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowCredentials: true
            maxAge: 3600
      routes:
        - id: LoginSignUpUsers
          uri: http://localhost:5001
          predicates:
            - Method=GET,POST
            - Path=/usersRegistration/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/usersRegistration/(?<segment>.*),/$\{segment}
          metadata:
            cors:
              allowedOrigins: http://localhost:63343
              allowedMethods: GET,POST
```

**Microservice where users login and sign up**

```
package webapplication.login_signup.RestApi;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("usersRegistration")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5000")
@Validated
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<UserModel> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/get/{email}/{password}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserModel> getUser(@Valid @PathVariable String email, @Valid @PathVariable String password) {
        UserModel user = userService.getUserByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        if (user != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public ResponseEntity<UserModel> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserModel userModel, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        UserModel createdUser = userService.createUser(userModel);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(createdUser);
        }
        if (createdUser == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdUser);
    }

}
```

Microservice Spring Security

```
package webapplication.login_signup.Security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/usersRegistration/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

**Frontend Javascript method get inf**

```
document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);

    const email = formData.get('email');
    const password = formData.get('password');

    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/usersRegistration/get/${email}/${password}`, {
        method: 'GET',

    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.statusText + " and " + response.status);
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Login failed. Invalid credentials.');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Login successful!', data);
            window.location.href = '..FrontendWebApplication/FrontEnd/nextPage.html';
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
            errorMessage.textContent = 'Invalid email or password!';
        });
});
```

To view and test the whole code can be found in this GitHub repo:
https://github.com/LyubomirD/WebApplication_Microservices

Thanks in advance to all of you!